# C++ Builder derived TComboBox to have Items by default

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, tcombobox

A VCL component newbie here, so pardon me if this is a stupid question...

I'm trying to make a TComboBox component with default items in it upon dropped onto the form, i.e. a TMonthComboBox that will have the list of months in its Items list, when dropped on the form.

I've found that trying to access the Items property during Construction will result in a "**Control '' has no parent window**" error if I try to drop such combobox on the form.

here is (part of) the constructor:

```
__fastcall TMonthCombo::TMonthCombo(TComponent *Owner):TComboBox(Owner)
{
    this->Style = csDropDownList; // this is okay
    this->Items->Add("January"); // This is causing problem
}
```

I figured that the problem is stemming from the fact that the Items property is not available yet at this point of the construction.

Is there anyway to make sure the component is ready to accept values into its Items property, within the component source code itself (i.e. not adding the list items in the Properties Editor at design time)?

Before anyone tells me to "Just add the items in your Application code at run time", I have to explain that this ComboBox will be used quite frequently in many places, and Month selection is just a simple example I used to explain the problem, the actual values I want to put in the ComboBox is much more varied and most of the time, dynamic in nature. It also have to response to the user selection in varied ways.

I have tried the run-time way, but it's getting very tedious. That's why I'm making it into a component, so that it will handle itself without me having to repeatedly input multiple versions of codes just to populate the ComboBoxes.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: After tried manlio's solution, the ComboBox has an odd look in run-time:[image]

The ComboBox has double image at run time. What have I done wrong?

```
__fastcall TYearCombo::TYearCombo(TComponent* Owner) : TComboBox(Owner), init_items(true)
{

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TYearCombo::CreateWnd()
{
    unsigned short yr, mn, dy;

    this->Width = 90;
    this->Style = csDropDownList;
    this->DropDownCount = 11;
    TDate d = Today();
    d.DecodeDate(&yr, &mn, &dy);
    year = yr;

    if (init_items)
    {
        init_items = false;
        TComboBox::CreateWnd();
        Items->BeginUpdate();
        for(int i=year-5; i<=year+5; i++)
        {
            Items->Add(IntToStr(i));
        }
        this->ItemIndex = 5;
        Items->EndUpdate();
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If I remove the this->Width = 90; line, then it is working perfectly.

Comment: Check this experiment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859524/where-to-initialize-subcomponent-parent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Override the `CreateWnd` virtual method and add a `init_items` private data member:

   ```
   class TMonthCombo : public TComboBox
   {
   // ...

   protected:
     virtual void __fastcall CreateWnd();

   private:
     bool init_items;

   // ...
   };
   ```
2. Set the `init_items` flag:

   ```
   TMonthCombo::TMonthCombo(TComponent *Owner) : TComboBox(Owner),
                                                 init_items(true)
   {
     // ...
   }
   ```
3. Inside `CreateWnd` you can add new items:

   ```
   void __fastcall TMonthCombo::CreateWnd()
   {
     TComboBox::CreateWnd();

     if (init_items)
     {
       init_items = false;
       Items->BeginUpdate();
       Items->Add("January");
       // ...
       Items->EndUpdate();
     }
   }
   ```

Further notes:

- ["Control has no parent" in Create ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18991382/3235496) (`TComboBox` requires an allocated `HWND` in order to store strings in its `Items` property).
- simply cast the constructor's `Owner` parameter to `TWinControl` and assign the result to the component's `Parent` property **isn't a solution**:

  ```
  TMonthCombo::TMonthCombo(TComponent *Owner) : TComBoBox(Owner)
  {
    Parent = static_cast<TWinControl *>(Owner);
    // ...
  }
  ```

  the assignment solves the *"Control has no parent window error"* but creates another problem: the form is always the component's parent (you cannot add the form to a different container).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and correction to my codes. The way you suggested is working, but created an odd phenomenon - the ComboBox has a double image at run-time. I edited my original post to include a screenshot and code.

Comment: `TMonthCombo::CreateWnd()` must call `TComboBox::CreateWnd()` regardless of the `init_items` value. As currently shown, if anything ever calls `RecreateWnd()` on the `TMonthCombo` or a (grand)parent control, `TMonthCombo` will lose its `HWND` and never create a new `HWND` again.

Comment: Also, *NEVER NEVER NEVER* assign the `Parent` property in the constructor! It is the responsibility of the caller to set the appropriate `Parent` after construction is finished.  The `Parent` can be different than the `Owner` (especially for components streamed from a DFM), and the `Owner` might not even be a `TWinControl` descendant to begin with. If you want to detect when a `Parent` has been assigned, override the virtual `SetParent()` method instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your notes about `CreateWnd()`, I've fixed the calling point. About the `Parent` property, the code shown is used to explain why the assignment **isn't** a solution.